# do you need COMMIT; after INSERT /*+ append */

Tags: oracle, commit, sql-insert

I have COMMIT after every INSERT statement.

I am wondering if I need to `COMMIT;` after `INSERT  /*+ append */` ...

Comment: This question will prove difficult to answer because whether or not you need a commit after every insert depends largely on what constitutes a transaction in your application.

Comment: You can consider using COMMIT WRITE BATCH NOWAIT

Answer (score 3):

You probably *don't* want to commit after every `INSERT`, but you probably *do* want to commit after every `INSERT /*+ APPEND */`.

For a conventional `INSERT`, you probably only want to commit when the application's logical transaction is complete. Unnecessarily committing after every conventional insert would cause problems with performance and atomicity.

For a direct-path `INSERT /*+ APPEND */`, you probably need to commit as soon as possible. Direct-path writes improve performance at the expense of extra locking (and other problems). That extra locking blocks every session, even the current session, from even reading the object until the transaction is committed. To avoid the error `ORA-12838: cannot read/modify an object after modifying it in parallel`, it is common for programs to commit after every `INSERT /*+ APPEND */`. (Although this error will not happen in Oracle 23c.)